Automatic translator from OData requests to GraphQL
I have an existing GraphQL endpoint, and I need to connect it to a service that understands OData for CRUD operations. Is it physically possible to write an automatic translator from OData requests to GraphQL? Is this generally the right direction for solving this problem?
Based on my preliminary analysis, it seems theoretically possible, but I'm concerned that I can't find any existing solutions for automatic conversion of OData requests to GraphQL. Therefore, I decided to ask here if I am on the right path with such a solution.
